# How do I prevent Google Tag Manager from appending javascript after html

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I recently began working on a client's site that has Google Tag Manager running on it. The following code was used to implement GTM:

```
<noscript><iframe src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PFTF46'
height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PFTF46');</script>
```

It appears to be tracking fine, but it's appending the following code to the bottom of the page after the content:

```
if (document.referrer.match(/google\.com/gi) && document.referrer.match(/cd/gi)) { var myString = document.referrer; var r = myString.match(/cd=(.*?)&/); var rank = parseInt(r[1]); var kw = myString.match(/q=(.*?)&/); if (kw[1].length > 0) { var keyWord = decodeURI(kw[1]); } else { keyWord = "(not provided)"; } var p = document.location.pathname; _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'RankTracker', keyWord, p, rank, true]); }
```

See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68b8Z.png) for a better understanding. When I removed the GTM tracking code, this Javascript was not appended to the bottom of the page, so I have at least isolated that GTM is adding it.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you.

The website in question is http://www.fleischersport.com

Comment: Try moving the GTM code inside the body. The noscript includes an iframe. The iframe should go inside the body.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your GTM interface.

The code you posted tries to retrieve the organic keyword from referrals via the Google SERP page. This is not something that GTM injects by itself (also it is something that does not work anymore). If this is injected by GTM then only because somebody configured a custom HTML tag.

Remove that tag if you do not want or need this.

Also GTM code is not "tracking code". GTM is a tag management system, not a tracking system, although it can be used to deploy tracking system. But it can also be used to deploy other things, including crap Javascript workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but GTM uses that code to work.

So if you want GTM to provide you with analytics, you will have to live with it appending code that it uses.

Or just remove GTM and you won't see the code being appending, but of course, you won't have analytics anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is pasted via GTM?,

GTM can paste code on the bottom of the page only when you includes a tag with custom HTML. Check if that code is inside your GTM. 
And consider that the pasted code is not the same that the one you see on the plataform because he compacts the code on the publishing tag process.

But the use of the _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'RankTracker', keyWord, p, rank, true]); , come from classic analytics, it sound more like there is another function pasting the code, the object _gaq is created when you use the the hardcode version of classic analytics

Also try to look in another computer if the code is added, that event of RankTracker sound like and add on on your browser